# Adjoint of the multiplication operator on a Sobolev space

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, real-analysis, operator-theory, sobolev-spaces

Let $f\colon\mathbb{R}^n\rightarrow\mathbb{C}$ be a bounded function with a bounded first derivative. Then the multiplication operator $H^1(\mathbb{R}^n)\ni x\mapsto A_f x:=fx\in H^1(\mathbb{R}^n)$ is bounded, where $H^1(\mathbb{R}^n)=W^{1,2}(\mathbb{R}^n)$, a [Sobolev space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sobolev_space#The_case_p_=_2). In [a comment](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/349742/square-root-of-multiplication-operator-on-sobolev-space/349743#349743), user ougoah asked whether the adjoint operator $A_f^*$ is  a multiplication operator, too. Here this question will be answered.

Answer (score 3):

$\newcommand{\R}{\mathbb R}$
The answer is: $A_f^*$ is a multiplication operator iff the function $f$ is constant.

Indeed, recall that for all $x$ and $y$ in $H^1:=H^1(\mathbb R^n)$
\begin{equation*}
 \langle x,y\rangle:=\langle x,y\rangle_{H^1}
 =\int\Big(x\bar y+\sum_{j=1}^n(D_jx)\,(D_j\bar y)\Big), 
\end{equation*}
where $\int:=\int_{\mathbb R^n}$ and $D_j$ denotes the partial derivative with respect to the $j$th argument.

The condition that $A_f^*$ is a multiplication operator $A_{\bar g}$ for some bounded function $g\colon\mathbb{R}^n\rightarrow\mathbb{C}$ with a bounded first derivative means that 
\begin{equation*}
 \langle fx,\bar z\rangle=:L(x,z)=R(x,z):=\langle x,\bar g\bar z\rangle \tag{1}
\end{equation*}
for all $x$ and $z$ in $H^1$.

So, the "if" part of our iff claim is obvious: if $f$ is constant, then $A_f^*=A_{\bar f}$.

To prove the "only if" part, take any $c=(c_1,\dots,c_n)$ and $a=(a_1,\dots,a_n)$ in $\R^n$ and let 
\begin{equation*}
 x(t):=e^{ia\cdot t-|t|^2/2}\quad\text{and}\quad z(t):=e^{i(c-a)\cdot t-|t|^2/2}
\end{equation*}
for $t=(t_1,\dots,t_n)\in\R^n$, where $a\cdot t:=\sum_1^n a_j t_j$ and $|t|:=\sqrt{t\cdot t}$. Then 
\begin{align*}
 R(x,z)&=\int\Big(gzx+\sum_{j=1}^n D_j(gz)\,D_jx\Big) \\ 
 &=\int gz\Big(x-\sum_{j=1}^n D_j^2x\Big) \\ 
& =\int dt\,g(t)e^{ic\cdot t-|t|^2/2}\sum_{j=1}^n(a_j^2+2ia_jt_j+\tfrac{n+1}n-t_j^2)
\end{align*}
and, similarly,
\begin{equation*}
 L(x,z)=\int dt\,f(t)e^{ic\cdot t-|t|^2/2}\sum_{j=1}^n((c_j-a_j)^2+2i(c_j-a_j)t_j+\tfrac{n+1}n-t_j^2). 
\end{equation*}
So, in view of (1), $L(x,z)$ and $R(x,z)$ are equal quadratic polynomials in $a_1$, for each $c\in\R^n$. Equating the coefficients of $a_1^2$ in these two polynomials, we see that 
$$\int dt\,f(t)e^{ic\cdot t-|t|^2/2}=\int dt\,g(t)e^{ic\cdot t-|t|^2/2}
$$
for all $c\in\R^n$, which implies $f=g$, which in turn means that (1) can be rewritten as (2) in the [previous answer](https://mathoverflow.net/a/349743/36721), whence, according to what follows formula (2) in that answer, $f$ is indeed constant.

Comment: Thank you for this detailed answer. I have asked another question about properties of $A_f^*$ over on StackExchange: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3502022/properties-of-the-adjoint-of-multiplication-on-sobolev-space.